# VBA - Error 424 usando worksheetfunction averageif

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un problema usando la función promedio.si a través del código de VBA. Me sale error 424 - se requiere un objeto VBA Excel, pero no soy capaz de localizar el problema:

```
vector = Worksheets(Hoja_datos).Range(Cells(Fila_in_dia, Col_dato), Cells(Fila_fin_dia, Col_dato))

c = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(vector, ">0")
```

Lo que quiero es calcular el promedio de los valores del vector que son mayores que 0.

La asignación del rango a la variable funciona correctamente, he comprobado en la ventana "Locales" que se asigna correctamente a la variable.

Entiendo que el fallo puede estar en el condicionante, pero no acabo de dar con la tecla...

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2):

Pues he intentado replicar el código y tu sintaxis funciona correctamente, así que vas a tener que revisar un par de cosas

```
Sub Media()
    Dim vector As Range
    Dim c As Double
    Set vector = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 3))

    c = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(vector, ">0")
    Range("D1").Value2 = c
End Sub
```

Este código funciona bien así que:

1-> Asegurate de declarar las variables, esto no es siempre esencial pero es una buena práctica, puedes escribir `Option explicit`al principio del modulo y vba te lo recordará cuando te olvides

2-> Cuando asignas un objeto a una variable, como es el caso de vector tienes que poner `Set` delante

3-> Yo he usado `ActiveSheet` por pereza, que da mas problemas que otra cosa, tu los has hecho mejor usando `Worksheets()` pero `Hoja_datos` tiene que ir entre comillas como string.

4-> Si no es nada de esto revisa que Fila_in_dia o Col_dato están bien elegidos

Espero que alguno de estos cambios soluciones tu error.

**EDIT:**
Hoja_datos, no tiene porque ir entre comillas, pero como en el código que pasaste no sale la definición de Hoja_datos ni pensé que podia ser una variable, fallo mío.

Comment: Solo un apunte, `Hoja_datos ` solo debe ir entre comillas si la hoja de datos se llama así, sin comillas si se trata de una variable que contiene el nombre de la hoja de datos.
Yo a puesto a que el problema es que falta `Dim vector As Range` pues es un error típico de VBA que en ocasiones confunde el tipo de objeto.

Comment: Pues también es verdad, ni pensé en ello xD. Voy a editarlo.

Comment: ¡Mil gracias a Jaime y Roger!

Al final la clave es el Set. Una vez puesto ha funcionado sin problemas.

Si declaras "vector" pero no pones el "Set", te salta error en la linea de asignación del rango (Error 91).

Menos mal pq estaba atascado por esta tontería. En cualquier caso me apunto la buena práctica de declarar las variables.

Saludos.

Comment: Si esta respuesta te funcionó, por favor, márcala como correcta para poder cerrar la pregunta. Gracias.